# Does socket.io allow registering different handlers for one single event?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vue.js, socket.io

When describing receiving events, [socket.io document](https://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-receiving-events) doesn't say whether I can use more one event handler for the same event or not. For example, I have two components both need to handle `io.on('connection' ...`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does socket.io allow registering different handlers for one single event?

Yes, it's just an `EventEmitter` like object and you can have as many handlers for a given event as you want.  Specifically, there is no problem having more than one of these:

```
io.on('connection', ...)
```